# WPML Localizing inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wpml

Well, I have this javascript code in my multilanguage wordpress website's header.php:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function calculateBmi() {
var weight = document.bmiForm.weight.value
var height = document.bmiForm.height.value
if(weight > 0 && height > 0){
var finalBmi = weight/(height/100*height/100)
document.bmiForm.bmi.value = finalBmi
if(finalBmi > 18.5 && finalBmi < 25){
document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Normal weight."
}
if(finalBmi > 25 && finalBmi < 30){
document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "You have overweight."
}
if(finalBmi > 30 && finalBmi < 35){
document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Overweight - I Stage."
}
if(finalBmi > 35 && finalBmi < 40){
document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Overweight - II Stage."
}
if(finalBmi > 40) {
document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Overweight - III Stage."
}
}
else{
alert("Please Fill in everything correctly")
}
}
//-->
</script>
```

And want to know how to translate it with WPML plugin.
Only these strings must be translated.

"Normal weight."
"You have overweight."
"Overweight - I Stage."
"Overweight - II Stage."
"Overweight - III Stage."

I asked on the official forum, but they are too slow for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a var for each string you want translated:

```
var normalWeight = <?php _e( 'Normal weight.', 'your-textdomain' ); ?>
var overweight =  <?php _e( 'You have overweight.', 'your-your-textdomain' ); ?>
```

etc....

Then, drop in the vars in their respective assignments:

```
document.bmiForm.meaning.value = overweight;
```

etc...